# RxJava thread still running after disposing disposable

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, rx-java, rx-java2

i am trying to build an app,which uses a lib for serial bt connections.  [harry1453 /
android-bluetooth-serial](https://github.com/harry1453/android-bluetooth-serial)

and i am connecting bt device like here,

```
bluetoothSerialDeviceSingle = bluetoothManager.openSerialDevice(mac);
  disposableConnection = bluetoothSerialDeviceSingle
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onConnected, this::onError);
```

even if i dispose this variables threads are still running and they are causing bugs

```
  disposableConnection.dispose();
  disposableConnection = null;
```

how can i dispose a disposable in a right way of rx-java2 ?

Comment: What threads are you referring to?

Comment: "io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: com.harrysoft.androidbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnectException: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1" error happens on this line, is this thread from library? i really did not understand idea of rx-java yet:( @Joni

Comment: That  happens when the observable produces an error after it has been disposed. It sounds like the observable returned by `bluetoothManager.openSerialDevice()` does not handle cancellation properly.

Comment: how should i dispose "Single<Object> bluetoothManager"? or should I get observable from "bluetoothManager" and destroy it?

Comment: This is a bug in  bluetoothManager. Is this `bluetoothManager` something from the github library you link to? Open a new "issue" for the project on the github page.

Comment: yes it's from github thanks :)